# ModelState Contains String Required Properties Twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm developing an Asp.Net Core 2.1 App using Razor Pages.I've come down with an odd behavior.The problem is when I submit a form,the client side validation passes with all required properties filled out,but then the validation fails with the ModelState.IsValid check,and the reason is that the ModelState contains the required string properties twice,one with the value entered and one with null value,So the validation fails!

> {[**BankName**, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary+ModelStateNode]}
>
> {[**BankAccount.BankName**, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary+ModelStateNode]}

See,**BankAccount** is the model class,and **BankName** is a required property.I don't know why the property appears twice in ModelState dictionary,one with the model name(with the data entered) and one without the modelname(with null value)
Any idea why this is happening?

```
 public class BankAccount
{
  [DisplayName("")]
    public int BankAccountId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [DisplayName("")]
    public string BankName { get; set; }
   ...
```

Here' the code OnPost() where the validation fails:

```
             public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        // TODO: Not ideal! But solves the problem of returning invalid model state.
        ModelState.Remove("BankName");
       
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToPage();
        }
        _context.BankAccounts.Add(BankAccount);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage();
    }
```

After searching a lot,I found a workaround,which isn't very ideal.That's to remove the additional property that has oddly been inserted in ModelState dictionary. I mean this line:

```
ModelState.Remove("BankName");
```

But that's not the right way.I'd like to figure out why it's happening?!

Here are two properties defined on the PageModel:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public BankAccount BankAccount { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public BankAccount BankAccountEdit { get; set; }
```

One is used to insert new BankAccount and the other one is used to edit existing ones by clicking on a button from the table.

Comment: Show us how your validation is set up.

Comment: This odd behavior happens when I have the list of BankAccounts on the top of page,and the Create form down the table.In fact,both the Create and Edit pages have been 

put on one page.If I have the Create page separately,everything works as expected,which means the ModelState wouldn't contain the additional property with null value.

Comment: Is your `BankAccount` class referenced by another model with validation?

Comment: Yeah,Look at the following code:

Comment: I am confused.  Your method `OnPostAsync` doesn't have any models at all.  What is it validating?

Comment: @Amy this is razor pages, the OP more than likely has a member on the PageModel tagged with `[BindProperty]` attribute.

Comment: @Amy Nothing special to validate except the validation attributes defined in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the the issue.The problem was that I have two properties of the same type(BankAccount class) in my page model,one for inserting new entity and the other one for editing existing entity all on the same page.
So to validate each form separately OnPost(),I used the following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var validateBankAccount = ModelState.GetFieldValidationState("BankAccount");
        if (validateBankAccount == 
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Invalid)
        {
            return RedirectToPage();
        }

        _context.BankAccounts.Add(BankAccount);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage();
    }
```